# Incorrect routing with wordpress rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a page setup with the permalink of `mydomain.com/events` which uses a page template. This page show all my events pulled in from an external source (so can't be a custom post type). I've then setup rewrites to handle a categories parameter to the url and then single events.

```
add_action('init', 'mydomain_events_rewrite');
function mydomain_events_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^events/categories/?$',
        'index.php?category=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^events/?$',
        'index.php?event=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'mydomain_events_rewrite_var');
function mydomain_events_rewrite_var($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'events';
    $vars[] = 'categories';
    return $vars;
}
```

So the idea is categories would just provide the category variable to the events page, for example `mydomain.com/events/categories/film`. And then individual events would be `mydomain.com/events/123/my-epic-film`.

As it stands, if I go to `mydomain.com/events` it just redirects me to the homepage. But if I use the rewrite urls, `mydomain.com/events/categories/film` it goes to a 404. Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was missing the correct regex and the page

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^events/category/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?pagename=events&category=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^events/([^/]*)?',
    'index.php?pagename=events&event=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```